# .pause is not working in an else statement

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Everything is working fine, only `audioElement1` is not getting paused which is described in the `else` statement, although the other feature of changing image written in the same `else` statement is working fine.... so how is this happening.... I am confused.

My HTML

```
<div class="second-song-list">
        <img class="second-img" src="images/covers/1.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="second-song-name">Warriyo - Mortals [NCS Release]</div>
        <div>4:03
          <img id="1"
            class="second-icon"
            src="images/circle-play-regular.png"
            alt="play/pause"
            srcset=""
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="second-song-list">
        <img class="second-img" src="images/covers/2.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="second-song-name">Cielo - Huma-Huma</div>
        <div>4:43
          <img id="2"
            class="second-icon"
            src="images/circle-play-regular.png"
            alt="play/pause"
            srcset=""
          />
        </div>
      </div>
```

My javascript

```
for (n = 0; n <= 9; n++) {
  var icon = document.querySelectorAll(".second-icon");

  icon[n].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    var x = e.target.getAttribute("id");
    audioElement1 = new Audio("songs/" + x + ".mp3");
    if (e.target.getAttribute("src") == "images/circle-play-regular.png") {
      e.target.setAttribute("src", "images/circle-pause-regular.png");
      audioElement1.play();
    } else {
      audioElement1.pause();
      e.target.setAttribute("src", "images/circle-play-regular.png");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: At first glance, `var icon = document.querySelectorAll(".second-icon");` should be outside the `for` loop.

Comment: @ths that would make no difference as the relevant part is `icon[n]` - it *should* be moved to reduce processing, but would have no functional impact.

Comment: It seems to me that you create a *new* Audio in variable audioElement1 then attempt to pause() it - given it's new, it's not started to play yet.   As you've not use `let audioElement1 =` then I would guess you have a global `var audioElement1` elsewhere (not included) so expecting `audioElement1.pause()` to pause the *previous* incarnation of audioElement1.  Move `audioElement1.pause();` to the line before `audioElement1 = new Audio`

Comment: @freedomn-m did I say it will solve the problem ? No, I didn't. Anyway, thanks for your comment, it explains the processing impact that I didn't mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each click you create a new `Audio` element:

```
for (n = 0; n <= 9; n++) {
  // ...
  icon[n].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // ...
    audioElement1 = new Audio("songs/" + x + ".mp3");
    if (e.target.getAttribute("src") == "images/circle-play-regular.png") {
      // ...
    } else {
      audioElement1.pause();
      e.target.setAttribute("src", "images/circle-play-regular.png");
    }
  });
}
```

So the one that you "pause" doesn't actually exist.  You probably just need to define `audioElement1' before the click handler and then wrap it in a closure or something to preserve the reference (since you are sharing the variable for each audioElement).

```
for (n = 0; n <= 9; n++) {
  var x = e.target.getAttribute("id");
  audioElement1 = new Audio("songs/" + x + ".mp3");
  (function(audioElement1, n) {
    icon[n].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    
      if (e.target.getAttribute("src") == "images/circle-play-regular.png") {
      // ...
      } else {
        audioElement1.pause();
        e.target.setAttribute("src", "images/circle-play-regular.png");
      }
    });
  })(audioElement1, n);
}
```

Comment: thanks mate, your comment's first line triggered the solution in my mind :)

Answer (score 0):

It's easier just to have the `<audio>` tag in HTML and hide it by not adding `controls` attribute to it. Having only one variable `audioElement1` to reference multiple Audio Objects is totally unnecessary (I thought impossible because it sounds ludicrous). Just to show other readers, in the example below the fourth `<audio>` has `controls` attribute. To prevent an exception, there's a dummy `<button>` that cannot be seen nor clicked. It's there since the event handlers on the `<audio>` expect a `<button>` -- normally you'd have it one way  (all hidden) or the other (all visible).

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// String is the common path to mp3s
const base = "https://assets.mixkit.co/sfx/preview/";
/*
This is an array of objects, each object has properties with unique
values
title to <figcaption>
time to <time>
file to <audio> which is interpolated to >base<
*/
const list = [{
  title: "Arcade retro game over",
  time: "00:01",
  file: "mixkit-arcade-retro-game-over-213.mp3"
}, {
  title: "Cinematic laser gun thunder",
  time: "00:04",
  file: "mixkit-cinematic-laser-gun-thunder-1287.mp3"
}, {
  title: "Small group cheer and applause",
  time: "00:10",
  file: "mixkit-small-group-cheer-and-applause-518.mp3"
}, {
  title: "Aggressive beast roar",
  time: "00:01",
  file: "mixkit-aggressive-beast-roar-13.mp3"
}];

// Collect all <audio> into a NodeList
const mp3s = document.querySelectorAll("audio");
/*
Each <audio> will get a url for it's `src` and will be registered to
the "playing" and "pause" events. The event handlers toggle the 
<button> associated with the <audio>.
*/
mp3s.forEach((audio, index) => {
  audio.src = `${base}${list[index].file}`;
  audio.onplaying = e => btns[index].classList.add("pause");
  audio.onpause = e => btns[index].classList.remove("pause");
});

// NodeList of <figcaption>
const caps = document.querySelectorAll("figcaption");
// Add the associated title
caps.forEach((caption, index) => caption.prepend(list[index].title));

// NodeList of <time>
const time = document.querySelectorAll("time");
// Add the associated time
time.forEach((time, index) => time.textContent = list[index].time);

// NodeList of <button>
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("button");
// Register each <button> to the "click" event when triggered call playPause()
btns.forEach((button, index) => button.onclick = playPause);

// Event handler that plays and pauses associated <audio>
function playPause(event) {
  const audio = this.closest("figcaption").querySelector("audio");
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.pause();
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 300 2ch/1.25 "Segoe UI"
}

ul {
  list-style: none
}

figure {
  display: list-item;
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

figure+figure {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

figcaption {
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

audio {
  width: 240px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

time {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  font-family: Consolas;
}

button {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button::before {
  content: "▶️";
}

button.pause::before {
  content: "⏸️"
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=240&h=135&random=1&txt=1&txtclr=fc0" alt="" />
    <figcaption>
      <br>
      <audio></audio>
      <time></time><button></button>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=240&h=135&random=1&txt=2&txtclr=fc0" alt="" />
    <figcaption>
      <br>
      <audio></audio>
      <time></time><button></button>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=240&h=135&random=1&txt=3&txtclr=fc0" alt="" />
    <figcaption>
      <br>
      <audio></audio>
      <time></time><button></button>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=240&h=135&random=1&txt=4&txtclr=fc0" alt="" />
    <figcaption>
      <br>
      <audio controls></audio>
      <!--Dummy button-->
      <button style="display: none"></button>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</ul>
```